# Nouveau driver issue

Tags: boot, kernel, bios, cpufreq, purge

The computer needs randomly two consecutive boots to start.

Here is what happened:

1. After installing `indicator-cpufreq` and running `openssl speed` together with `turbostat`, I needed two boots to start Ubuntu.

   - So I removed it, but I had a "kernel panic" message at first boot and normal login message at second boot
   - Therefore, I purged indicator-cpufreq : `sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove indicator-cpufreq`
   - Then, I still needed two boots, but the first did not have a kernel panic message anymore.
2. After what, I reinstalled indicator-cpufreq and had randomly :

   - frozen screen when the system found the soundcard
   - frozen screen when the system found the network connection
   - kernel panic
   - first boot stopping a bit after the message "A job is running for..."
3. Finally, I purged indicator-cpufreq again. Now the first boot stops a bit after the message "A job is running for..." around the messages that it had found the network connection or the soundcard.

Noticeable :

- when the message "A job is running for..." is preceded by (x of 6), there seems to always be an error
- when it is preceded by (x of 5), the boot process seems to stop and restart.
- when it is preceded by (x of 4), the boot process seems to end with the login screen.

---

Furthermore, my BIOS is broken : (from dmesg)

```
[    0.000000] ------------[ cut here ]------------
[    0.000000] Your BIOS is broken; DMAR reported at address fed90000 returns all ones!
               BIOS vendor: Hewlett-Packard; Ver: 786F1 v01.24; Product Version: 
[    0.000000] WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 0 at /build/linux-S9wgEU/linux-4.15.0/drivers/iommu/dmar.c:848 warn_invalid_dmar.part.11+0x55/0x70
[    0.000000] Modules linked in:
[    0.000000] CPU: 0 PID: 0 Comm: swapper Not tainted 4.15.0-49-generic #53-Ubuntu
[    0.000000] Hardware name: Hewlett-Packard HP Compaq dc7800 Convertible Minitower/0AACh, BIOS 786F1 v01.24 03/18/2008
[    0.000000] EIP: warn_invalid_dmar.part.11+0x55/0x70
[    0.000000] EFLAGS: 00210092 CPU: 0
[    0.000000] EAX: 0000008b EBX: c7b6b6b5 ECX: 00000080 EDX: 00000000
[    0.000000] ESI: fed90000 EDI: 00000000 EBP: c7c13ed0 ESP: c7c13ea0
[    0.000000]  DS: 007b ES: 007b FS: 00d8 GS: 00e0 SS: 0068
[    0.000000] CR0: 80050033 CR2: 00000000 CR3: 07e24000 CR4: 000006b0
[    0.000000] Call Trace:
[    0.000000]  dmar_validate_one_drhd+0xc9/0x140
[    0.000000]  dmar_walk_remapping_entries+0x92/0x1e0
[    0.000000]  detect_intel_iommu+0x58/0xd7
[    0.000000]  ? xen_swiotlb_init+0x3f0/0x3f0
[    0.000000]  pci_iommu_alloc+0x45/0x5f
[    0.000000]  mem_init+0x28/0x204
[    0.000000]  start_kernel+0x217/0x438
[    0.000000]  i386_start_kernel+0xa1/0xa5
[    0.000000]  startup_32_smp+0x164/0x168
[    0.000000] Code: 00 00 00 e8 9e db 1a 00 89 45 f0 b8 01 00 00 00 e8 91 db 1a 00 8b 4d ec 8b 55 f0 51 52 50 53 57 56 68 e4 ad b6 c7 e8 2b 8d af ff <0f> 0b 83 c4 1c 8d 65 f4 5b 5e 5f 5d c3 8d b4 26 00 00 00 00 8d
[    0.000000] ---[ end trace 0f18a8dcfe7fc25e ]---
```

---

Comment: The problem may not be with your nouveau driver, but with your BIOS, as my answer addresses.

Comment: The fact that Synaptic refuses the uninstall the current Nouveau driver and install the new version is an issue anyway. And it is related to the bug as changing driver solves the problem.

Comment: It doesn't solve the problem, it just works around the problem.

Comment: The admin has locked the BIOS, so I can't access it. It's not my personal computer.

Comment: Talk to your admin about your problem, and that your BIOS is very old, and needs an update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solved by selecting

> NVIDIA binary driver - version 340.107

instead of

> X.Org X server -- Nouveau display driver

in the "Software & updates" tab from the "Updates Manager" window

[ScreenshotOfTheWindowFromWhichTheProblemWasSolved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1x5CP.png)

- If I select the Nouveau driver back again, the issue reappears : two boots are needed and the first one randomly triggers a "kernel panic" ; freezes at "found soundcard" or "found network connection" ; or reboots by it-self.
- If I remove the nouveau driver :

  `xserver-xorg-video-nouveau (version 1:1.0.15-2)`

  then reinstall it and reuse it, the problem reappears.
- If I try to install the more recent package :

  `xserver-xorg-video-nouveau-hwe-18.04 (version 1:1.0.15-3)`

  with Synaptic, the system answers to fix broken packages first. But when I try to fix broken packages, the system answers that the broken packages are marked to "keep as they are".

Answer (score 0):

Update your older BIOS via https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/hp-compaq-dc7800-small-form-factor-pc/3459241 and this should bring you up to current, and may (really) solve your problem.

Also, your Nvidia driver may be outdated, as the latest version is 418.56, but it depends on the model of your card.

Comment: How do you change the BIOS ? Wine tries to install it at "`c:\...`" but it doesn't produce any change.

Comment: @thomasb-user140297 You can't use Wine to do the BIOS update. Read the instructions that came with the update, or I think I saw an updater app on the web site which probably requires Windows to run.

Comment: The computer is a "HP Compaq dc7800 Convertible Minitower PC", but only FreeDOS and Windows are selectable in the operating system field. It's rather old, the graphic card is a "`G86 [Quadro NVS 290]`"

Comment: You should be able to boot FreeDOS form USB. The trick is to put the BIOS updater into the FreeDOS USB so that you can run it from FreeDOS. The instructions should be somewhere on the web I guess.

Comment: @thomasb-user140297 Do you not have Windows dual-boot on your system?

Comment: @user68186 later, as I would need to learn many new things.

Comment: @heynnema no dual boot, there is only Ubuntu on the computer

Comment: @thomasb-user140297 Then you'll either need to try the FreeDOS method (it shouldn't require too much learning), or find a way to boot to a HDD with Windows on it.

Comment: Later, for now, I'm not going to change the BIOS. Besides, Synaptic refuses to update the driver which is suspicious.

Comment: @thomasb-user140297 fair enough. Remember though, that your current BIOS is from 2008, and Ubuntu calls it out as broken.